# Dynamic regular expression with variable in Apache SSL?

Tags: regex, apache, ssl

We got request to filter requests by client certificate. And I'm wondering if is it possible to have Apache SSL related variable in regular expression.

We came up we idea to make something like this:

```
<Location />
SSLRequire (%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_OU} eq "SPRL-D" and %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m/^.*%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}.*/)
</Location>
```

But this produces an error in regular expression compilation. We tried lot of things regarding regular expression (eg. playing with `\` and `()`) but the result is same.

How to include variables in regular expression parts of condition?

Comment: Not unless it's so documented. Off topic for SO. Try serverfault.com.